# Reliability of Random with a constant seed across different versions of Java

Tags: java, random

In our application, we use Random and SecureRandom to generate some very large sets of information for some clients. After some measurements, we realized that it was faster and less memory-intensive to re-generate the information using seeds stored on disk, than to store and read that information. I looked through the javadoc, and I didn't see anything guaranteeing that, given a *constant* seed n, the result of, say, `new Random(n).nextInt()` shall be the same across different versions of Java.

**My question is**: is this a safe assumption to make for Java 8 and previous versions, that `new Random(n).nextInt()` in Java 8 shall return the same value than in previous versions of Java?

(For the sake of fairness, I will accept answers answering the above question, even if they don't answer the question below.)

While I know there is no guarantee that this will also be true for later versions of Java, and that this second question shall solicit some opinions, what do you think are the odds that future Java version will change the algorithm used to generate pseudo-random numbers using Random and SecureRandom?

Thanks!

Comment: You could store the sequence of random numbers and regenerate the information from that sequence, which you know will always be accurate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed for `Random` in all versions through Java 8. There don't seem to be any similar guarantees for `SecureRandom` however.

If you look at the [Javadocs for Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), you can see this:

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers. **In order to guarantee this property, particular algorithms are specified for the class Random. Java implementations must use all the algorithms shown here for the class Random, for the sake of absolute portability of Java code.** However, subclasses of class Random are permitted to use other algorithms, so long as they adhere to the general contracts for all the methods.

Emphasis mine. So some thought was clearly given to this concern, and the decision was to specify the underlying algorithms in the documentation for the class. People could theoretically provide a differing implementation, but then it wouldn't be in compliance with the Java specification.

For further evidence, look at what that implementation is between versions. For example, the `next` method is defined the exact same way in every version since at least Java 1.4 (as far back as I looked).

```
seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
return (int)(seed >>> (48 - bits));
```

Since this is the same, you have a clear guarantee that, not only will the values returned be the same across versions, but you can reliably calculate the same values yourself using this algorithm.

However, I can't find any similar guarantees for `SecureRandom`, and since `Random` says that subclasses are free to break this rule, then it's not guaranteed that it will be consistent between versions. The only evidence I can find for this though is [a forum post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/505114/Security/SecureRandom-PRNG-consistent-java) of someone observing inconsistent values being generated with it. According to [Ian McLaird's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33171753/2499035), `SecureRandom` does seem to be generating consistent values in practice, so you might decide it's worth the risk to assume it will work. However, this behavior does not seem to be guaranteed.

To answer the second part of your question, it's theoretically possible that they could change it. However, since it is currently a well-defined operation, and given how hard Oracle works to avoid breaking backwards compatibility, I'd consider it incredibly unlikely.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the answer I was looking (and hoping!) for! I don't know why I missed the part you emphasized... Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Strictly, though, that note from the javadocs only applies to the *current* release.  All Java 7 implementations must use the same algorithms.  That's not really a promise that they won't change it from 8 - 9.  But I agree with you that seems *incredibly* unlikely.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of SecureRandom.setSeed(), it seems likely they have taken steps *not* to make SecureRandom seedable in the same way as standard random: "The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed. Thus, repeated calls are guaranteed never to reduce randomness." -- their focus were probably secure randomness :D

Answer (score 3):

To directly answer your exact question: "Is this a safe assumption for Java 8 and earlier versions?"  I did this (Handy that I keep some old JDKs around for just such occasions).

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Random = " + new Random(0).nextInt());
        System.out.println("SecureRandom = " + new SecureRandom(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0}).nextInt());
    }
}
```

And the Results:

```
> & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javac.exe' .\RandomTest.java
> & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe' RandomTest
Random = -1155484576
SecureRandom = -1439655693

> & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javac.exe' .\RandomTest.java
> & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe' RandomTest
Random = -1155484576
SecureRandom = -1439655693

> & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\javac.exe' .\RandomTest.java
> & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe' RandomTest
Random = -1155484576
SecureRandom = -1439655693
```

So yes.  It appears, empirically, that it's a safe assumption for at *least* Java 6, 7, and 8.

**EDIT**
Updated above for `SecureRandom`.  `SecureRandom` doesn't have a constructor that takes an `int` so I seeded with four bytes of zeroes (for the same 32 bits).  The behavior is consistent for all tested versions of Java, but *does not give the same result as `java.util.Random`*.

Comment: Are the results same with SecureRandom?

Comment: I also predicted the same.Thanks for saving time by confirmation.